# How do I start talking in the chat room?

Tags: support

I've tried to use the Blender chat room and I can see posts there but I can't find any way to start to talk. I clicked everything imaginable and I could not get in.
Help? Thanks.

Comment: This is actually the right place to ask, and welcome to Blender.SE!

Answer (score 4):

You need [**20 rep** to talk in chat](https://blender.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat). You can see [your current site privileges here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/privileges). Also, this should have been on a banner when you entered the chatroom.

> ### Why do I need 20 rep to talk in chat?
>
> Your reputation on chat is the same as your reputation on the parent site.
>
> You can always enter chat rooms and listen with no rep at all.
>
> We can't allow anonymous participation on chat, so we require a small
>   bit of parent site reputation to ensure that chat is reserved for
>   active, engaged members of the community.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the 20 reps,
I think something in a database somewhere might get updated only overnight. Yesterday I had over 20 reps but could only read the chat but not talk - but when I tried again today, I got in and could talk with no problem.

Comment: Yes, the cache sometimes takes a while to refresh.